# How can I make my box not touching the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like to know a way so that my box does not touch the bottom of the page.
I'm using Bootstrap 4, tried the spacing utilities but it doesn't seem to work.

[image]

Here's a picture of how it is now, it's actually at the bottom of the page.

```
.signup {
  position:absolute;
  border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  display:grid;
  place-content:center;
  padding:2em 2em;
  border-radius:6px;
}
```

Comment: since you're using bootstrap4, you can add class `mb-5` or `mb-4` that should work for this specific case, also you can add class `shadow` to check if that's really away form the bottom.

Comment: @theTradeCoder : Thank you for your answer but unfortunately, the spacing utilities didn't seem to work for my case. As **Siddharth Shyniben** said, it's probably caused by the `position: absolute` that I stupidly forgot. I have to remove it to make the spacing utilities works. I think I will do, but not for now, his solution seems working, so I'm gonna settle for that. [Here's a preview of the result!](https://i.imgur.com/egov9g4.png)

Comment: Well, what I finally found, you may also need to every single thing to code like that wherever you need to get things away from the bottom, for that case you can add some bottom padding to the main container or (body) one time, and then you'll never need to make it every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using translate like so:

```
.signup {
  transform: translateY(-10%)
}
```

I think that `position: absolute` is the problem.

You can visit [this](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) to find out more about centering: It's very helpful!

Comment: Edited your code, and it works perfect!
I've tried `transform: translateY(-2em);` ! Thank you for this helpful link, and this solution!

Comment: [Preview](https://i.imgur.com/egov9g4.png) Seems working!